# Doubts about navigation bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

I'm trying to create a navigation bar with a drop down menu.

I want **HOME, FIXTURES, RESULTS,LEADERBOARD** to be on the same line. I want **UPCOMING WEEK,MONTHS** to be the drop down child of **FIXTURES** and **GOALS,ASSISTS** to be the child of **LEADERBOARD.** Even though i have applied the **display:inline** property to the first level li tags, RESULTS and **LEADERBOARD** are on different line.
whats the reason for this  and how do I correct it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .wrap{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  }

  .wrap>ul>li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 40px;
  }
  .drop li{
    list-style: none;
    
  }

  .wrap ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:white;
  }


</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fixtures</a></li>
        <ul class="drop">
          <li><a href="#">Upcoming Week</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Month</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Results</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Leaderboard</a></li>
        <ul class="drop">
          <li><a href="#">Goals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Assists</a></li>
        </ul>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the effect you're looking for?

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap>ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrap>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}

.drop li {
  list-style: none;
}

.wrap ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Fixtures</a>
      <ul class="drop">
        <li><a href="#">Upcoming Week</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Month</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Results</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Leaderboard</a>
      <ul class="drop">
        <li><a href="#">Goals</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Assists</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah! Thanks..  but what do these display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; mean?

Comment: display: flex is css flexbox layout, justify-content: space-between means put the first element at the beginning, last element at the end, and elements in between are separated evenly. Here's a tutorial on flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!